# Dimension error in neural network model for classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, compiler-errors, lstm, multiclass-classification

Below is the code for Hierarchical Attention Networks, taken from  https://github.com/arunarn2/HierarchicalAttentionNetworks. The only difference in the code on the link and mine is that I have 3 classes for classification, whereas they are using 2

```py
maxlen = 100
max_sentences = 15
max_words = 20000
embedding_dim = 100
validation_split = 0.2
#class defining the custom attention layer
class HierarchicalAttentionNetwork(Layer):
    def __init__(self, attention_dim):
        self.init = initializers.get('normal')
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.attention_dim = attention_dim
        super(HierarchicalAttentionNetwork, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        self.W = K.variable(self.init((input_shape[-1], self.attention_dim)))
        self.b = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim,)))
        self.u = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim, 1)))
        self.trainable_weightss = [self.W, self.b, self.u]
        super(HierarchicalAttentionNetwork, self).build(input_shape)

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return mask

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        # size of x :[batch_size, sel_len, attention_dim]
        # size of u :[batch_size, attention_dim]
        # uit = tanh(xW+b)
        uit = K.tanh(K.bias_add(K.dot(x, self.W), self.b))

        ait = K.exp(K.squeeze(K.dot(uit, self.u), -1))

        if mask is not None:
            # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting
            ait *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
        ait /= K.cast(K.sum(ait, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
        weighted_input = x * K.expand_dims(ait)
        output = K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], input_shape[-1]
# building Hierachical Attention network
embedding_matrix = np.random.random((len(word_index) + 1, embedding_dim))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=maxlen, trainable=True, mask_zero=True)

sentence_input = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sentence_input)
lstm_word = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True))(embedded_sequences)
attn_word = HierarchicalAttentionNetwork(100)(lstm_word)
sentenceEncoder = Model(sentence_input, attn_word)

review_input = Input(shape=(max_sentences, maxlen), dtype='int32')
review_encoder = TimeDistributed(sentenceEncoder)(review_input)
lstm_sentence = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True))(review_encoder)
attn_sentence = HierarchicalAttentionNetwork(100)(lstm_sentence)
preds = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(attn_sentence)
model = Model(review_input, preds)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])

print("model fitting - Hierachical attention network")
```

Following is the error I get. Please help me understand what the error means and how I can possibly resolve it.

[image: Error stacktrace]

Comment: Can you copy and paste the entire traceback, please? Generally speaking, avoid using figures for code/text.

Comment: You need to transpose one of your tensors to get the dimensions to match up. You can see in the error that one is `[?, 15, 100]`, and one is `[?, 100, 15]`. Those should both be the same. Without the full traceback, it's hard to say what line is causing the issue.